# A boundary version of Cauchy's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

I am looking for a reference for the following theorem (or something like it) that is not Kodaira's book.

> > Let $D$ be a domain and $\overline{D}$ be it's closure. Suppose that $f:\overline{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic in $D$ and continuous on $\overline{D}$. If the boundary of $D$, denoted $\partial D$ is composed of piecewise $C^1$ curves then
> >     $$f(w) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\partial D}\frac{f(z)}{z-w}dz$$
> >     for all $w\in D$.

This is stronger than the classical Cauchy integral theorem, because here we can allow the path we integrate over to be the boundary. This appears in Kodaira's book, but the book seems sloppily written and I found an egregious error in the first few pages, so I'd like another reference.

This does not appear in Ahlfors or any other standard text I looked at. I am looking for any proof that extends to usual Cauchy's theorem to allow paths that lie on the boundary of a region, instead of requiring them to lie entirely in the open region like the usual version does.

I managed to find [a paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1086062/pdf/pnas01805-0066.pdf) that sketches a high-powered proof when the boundary is a rectifiable Jordan arc (or some multiply connected region where each boundary component is) and gives a reference to a more elementary proof of the same result. I think a simpler proof should be possible in this case, where the boundary is assumed to be $C^1$.

This is closely related to an [old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178541/a-boundary-version-of-cauchys-integral-theorem) that did not get much attention.

Comment: Are we allowed to use [Carathéodory's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(conformal_mapping)) when $D$ is simply connected?

Comment: @Landscape Sure.

Comment: Sorry, only Carathéodory's theorem cannot provide any regularity/smoothness of the conformal map on the boundary, so we need some more powerful theorem if we want to use an argument by mapping $D$ conformally to a disk when D is simply connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess here that you mean that the boundary of $D$ is a finite number of pairwise disjoint curves. In this case, this Cauchy formula follows directly from Mergelyan's Theorem about uniform rational approximation of holomorphic functions. Indeed, the formula holds for rational functions with poles outside $\overline{D}$, and Mergelyan's Theorem says that any $f$ continuous on $\overline{D}$, holomorphic in $D$, can be approximated uniformly on $\overline{D}$ by rational functions with poles outside $\overline{D}$.

It also works under the weaker hypothesis that the curves are rectifiable.

Comment: Malik, you have consistently been very helpful when I have asked questions about complex analysis on here. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, I am glad that my answers helped you.

Comment: I think the argument in your answer is just the same as the argument in [the paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1086062/pdf/pnas01805-0066.pdf) mentioned by @Potato in the question. I wonder, as asked in Potato's original question, is there any other proof without using Mergelyan's Theorem, at least when the boundary has some smoothness?

Comment: @Landscape : Oh, I didn't look at the paper before answering the question. It is the same argument indeed. I don't know about other proofs, but why not use Mergelyan's Theorem? It is a classical and well-known result.

Comment: @MalikYounsi: I agree with you, but I still look forward to a more elementary proof.

Answer (score 2):

For domains with (piecewise) $C^1$ boundary, there is a simple proof using Stokes' theorem, at least if you assume that $f$ extends to $C^1$ on $\bar D$. A little computation will show that for $f \in C^1(\bar D)$,

$$2\pi i f(w) = \int_{\partial D} \frac{f(z)}{z-w}\,dz + \iint_D \frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}}{z-w}\,dz\wedge d\bar z,$$
from which your version of Cauchy's theorem follows.

I'll try to dig up a reference for the $C(\bar D)$ case.

Comment: Thanks. There is a proof sketched here, with reference to a more elementary proof by Denjoy: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1086062/pdf/pnas01805-0066.pdf . Unfortunately, I cannot find the Denjoy paper.

Comment: The sketched proof appears to work, but I'm having difficulty tracking down the citations.

Comment: Actually, those theorems are much stronger than what I want. There should be a simpler proof when the boundaries are $C^1$.

Comment: @Potato For domains with $C^2$ boundary, I think Ted's argument can be modified. Then there is a $C^1$ vector field normal to $\partial D$, and we can push inwards to get uniform continuity on a sequence of curves tending to $\partial D$.

Comment: @mrf, I suspect $C^1$ is good enough, because we only need a continuous collar :) Nope, I retract [ha!] this, because then we won't know the resulting "inner" curve is piecewise-$C^1$. But can't we approximate the $C^1$ curve by a $C^2$ curve as close as we want and proceed?

Comment: @Ted That's why I wanted $C^2$, but I agree it should be possible to salvage.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "a bit of computation" please? I don't really see how you got the formula in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

My apologies on my misreading the first time. Knowing $f$ is continuous on $\overline D$, for $\delta>0$ with $|w|<1-\delta$, we will know that the Cauchy integrand
$$\frac{f(z)}{z-w}$$
is uniformly continuous on $\{z: 1-\delta\le z\le 1\}$, and so the integral over the circle of radius $1-\delta$ converges to the integral over $\partial D$.

Comment: This settles things for the unit disc. But $D$ was an arbitrary $C^1$ domain.

Comment: It seems natural that this same approach would work for any arbitrary multiply-connected region (just find arcs that limit to to boundary uniformly). It seems tricky to write down the details, however.

Comment: OK, so without the Jordan curve theorem, we're stuck. But if I get to assume piecewise $C^1$-boundary, then I'm fine (without assuming a $C^1$ extension to the boundary) :) This is probably why the proof in Kodaira is so technical. ... @Potato, if we have a $C^1$ (or piecewise-$C^1$) boundary, then we can take a collar (following the normal vectors a distance $\delta$ for $\delta$ sufficiently small) and apply my same argument.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not quite sure how to handle the "corners." Could you provide a little more detail?

Comment: It's confusing having this thread running on two separate answers :) Actually, I am in trouble, because I first need to shrink $\partial D$ before I can wiggle to get a $C^2$ curve that's inside the original $\overline D$. Yeah, the details with corners get a bit thorny: Depending on the angle at the corner, we'll either have to chop off a bit of the curves if they extend past the intersection point or join their endpoints with a line segment.

Comment: I'm going out to dinner momentarily, but will try to think about this more later. This is a great question.