# Cauchy's integral theorem and domain boundaries

Tags: complex-analysis

On a homework assignment, I was asked if the following statement is true.

If $f(z)$ is analytic in a simply connected domain $D$ and continuous in $\partial D$ then $\oint_{\partial D} f(z) = 0$.

Is this statement correct?

It's very similar to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10831/example-of-continuous-function-that-is-analytic-on-the-interior-but-cannot-be-an), but continuity of $f(z)$ on the boundary might make it true. I just want to know if I should bother try to look for counter examples.

I have put a lot of thought into the problem and researched it. I noticed it came up a few times on the Math Stack Exchange in various forms, but I haven't been seen a concrete answer to the question in the way that it is phrased. I apologize in advance if this question is obvious or already answered.

Comment: Is true if $\partial D$ is regular enough: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392881/a-boundary-version-of-cauchys-theorem.

Comment: Say, you know that Cauchy integral formula is right on the boundary. What's the way to prove that Cauchy integral theorem is right too?