# Cauchy integration theorem for only continuous in the boundary

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I'm reading the proof of a general version for the Cauchy integration theorem:

> (**Theorem**)Let $\Gamma$ be a rectifiable Jordan curve, $R$ be the interior of $C$, $f(z)$ be a continuous function in the closed region $\overline{R}$ and a holomorphic function in $R$, then
> $$\int_\Gamma f(z) \text{d} z = 0$$

The mainly feature of this version of Cauchy integration theorem is that it does not require $f(z)$ to be holomorphic in $\overline{R}$.A related question asked is [Cauchy's integral theorem and domain boundaries](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1123090/cauchys-integral-theorem-and-domain-boundaries). For the preparation I read the proof of the normal version of Cauchy integration theorem in [Tao's blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2016/10/02/math-246a-notes-3-cauchys-theorem-and-its-consequences/).

In the references I found, the key for the proof is the following lemma (quoted from [Wikipedia#Green's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem), and it's also Theorem 4 in [the thesis Green's theorem and Jordan rectifiable curve by Yonghyo Jun Moon](https://open.bu.edu/bitstream/handle/2144/30144/Moon_Yonghyo_1963_web.pdf). It is a much easier reference to access for the proof of this lemma than Apostol's Mathematical Analysis):

> **(Decomposition Lemma)** — Assume $\Gamma$  is a rectifiable, positively oriented Jordan curve in the plane and let $R$ be its inner region. For every positive real $\delta$ , let ${\mathcal {F}}(\delta )$ denote the collection of squares in the plane bounded by the lines $x=m\delta ,y=m\delta $, where $m$ runs through the set of integers. Then, for this $\delta$ , there exists a decomposition of $\overline {R}$ into a finite number of non-overlapping subregions in such a manner that
>
> 1. Each one of the subregions contained in $R$, say $R_{1},R_{2},\ldots ,R_{k}$, is a square from ${\mathcal {F}}(\delta )$.
> 2. Each one of the remaining subregions, say $\displaystyle R_{k+1},\ldots ,R_{s}$, has as boundary a rectifiable Jordan curve formed by a finite number of arcs of $\Gamma$  and parts of the sides of some square from $\displaystyle {\mathcal {F}}(\delta )$.
> 3. Each one of the border regions $ R_{k+1},\ldots ,R_{s}$ can be enclosed in a square of edge-length $2\delta$.
> 4. If $\Gamma _{i}$ is the positively oriented boundary curve of $R_{i}$, then $\Gamma =\Gamma _{1}+\Gamma _{2}+\cdots +\Gamma _{s}.$
> 5. The number $s-k$ of border regions is no greater than $ 4\!\left({\frac {\Lambda }{\delta }}+1\right)$, where $\Lambda$  is the length of $\Gamma$.

Using this lemma, the proof for the theorem is: (I'm quoting it from quite old Chinese paper and I'm confusing the red sentences)

*Proof*. Since $f(z)$ is conitinuous in $\overline{R}$, it's uniformly continuous in $\overline{R}$. For any $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $0 < \delta < 1$ such that for any $| z_1 - z_2 | < 4 \delta $ in $\overline{R}$, $|f(z_1) - f(z_2)| < \varepsilon$.

Using the lemma and its notation, and $\color{red}{\text{we}}$ $\color{red}{\text{may}}$ $\color{red}{\text{assume}}$ $\color{red}{\text{every}}$ $\color{red}{\text{square}}$ $\color{red}{\text{in}}$ $\color{red}{\mathcal{F}(\delta)}$ $\color{red}{\text{has}}$ $\color{red}{\text{no}}$ $\color{red}{\text{one}}$ $\color{red}{\text{or}}$ $\color{red}{\text{more}}$ $\color{red}{\text{borders}}$ $\color{red}{\text{that}}$ $\color{red}{\text{separates}}$ $\color{red}{\text{some}}$ $\color{red}{\Gamma_i}$ $\color{red}{\text{into}}$ $\color{red}{\text{two}}$ $\color{red}{\text{simple}}$ $\color{red}{\text{Jordan}}$ $\color{red}{\text{curves}}$ $\color{red}{\text{such}}$ $\color{red}{\text{that}}$ $\color{red}{\text{one}}$ $\color{red}{\text{of}}$ $\color{red}{\text{them}}$ $\color{red}{\text{is}}$ $\color{red}{\text{a}}$ $\color{red}{\text{border}}$ $\color{red}{\text{of}}$ $\color{red}{\text{the}}$ $\color{red}{\text{square.}}$ $\color{red}{\text{Otherwise}}$ $\color{red}{\text{we}}$ $\color{red}{\text{may}}$ $\color{red}{\text{just}}$ $\color{red}{\text{replace}}$ $\color{red}{\Gamma_i}$ $\color{red}{\text{with}}$ $\color{red}{\text{the}}$ $\color{red}{\text{two}}$ $\color{red}{\text{simple}}$ $\color{red}{\text{Jordan}}$ $\color{red}{\text{curve.}}$$\color{red}{\text{(}}$$\color{red}{\text{what}}$ $\color{red}{\text{does}}$ $\color{red}{\text{the}}$ $\color{red}{\text{assumption}}$ $\color{red}{\text{use}}$ $\color{red}{\text{for,}}$ $\color{red}{\text{and}}$ $\color{red}{\text{how}}$ $\color{red}{\text{does}}$ $\color{red}{\text{the}}$ $\color{red}{\text{argument}}$ $\color{red}{\text{work?)}}$

Using the simplest version of Cauchy integeration theorem, we have $\int_{\Gamma_i} f(z) \text{d} z =0$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$. Hence

$$
\int_{\Gamma} f(z) \text{d} z = \sum_{i=k+1}^{s} \int_{\Gamma_i}f(z) \text{d}z
$$

Denote the length of $\Gamma_{i}$ as $\Lambda_{i}$. Obviously $\sum_{i=k+1}^{s} \Lambda_i - \Lambda$ is not greater than the perimeter of those square of edge-length $2\delta$ enclosing $ R_{k+1},\ldots ,R_{s}$. Again by the lemma, and $\delta < 1$, ($\color{red}{\text{The}}$ $\color{red}{\text{paper}}$ $\color{red}{\text{estimates}}$ $\color{red}{\text{in}}$ $\color{red}{\text{a}}$ $\color{red}{\text{result}}$ $\color{red}{\text{less}}$ $\color{red}{\text{than}}$ $\color{red}{17\Lambda + 16}$, so is the proof of Green's Theorem in wikipedia, but I doesn't understand how it could be $17\Lambda + 16$)

$$
\sum_{i=k+1}^{s} \Lambda_i \leq \Lambda + 8\delta \cdot 4(\frac{\Lambda}{\delta}+1) < 33 \Lambda + 32
$$

Let $z_0$ be a point in $\overline{R_i}$ for some $k+1 \leq i \leq s$, then by the uniformly convergent assumpsion, we have

$$
\big|\int_{\Gamma_i} [f(z)-f(z_0) ] \text{d}z\big| < \varepsilon \Lambda_i
$$

But since

$$
\int_{\Gamma_i} [f(z)-f(z_0) ] \text{d}z = \int_{\Gamma_i} f(z) \text{d}z - f(z_0) \int_{\Gamma_i} \text{d}z = \int_{\Gamma_i} f(z) \text{d}z 
,$$

hence

$$
\big|\int_{\Gamma_i} f(z) \text{d} z \big| < \varepsilon \Lambda_i.
$$

for any $k+1 \leq i \leq s$. Hence
$$
\big|\int_{\Gamma} f(z) \text{d} z \big| < \varepsilon(33 \Lambda + 32)
$$

Since $\varepsilon$ is any positive real number, we have

$$
\int_{\Gamma} f(z) \text{d} z = 0.
$$

My questions are:

1. What is the red sentence used for and how its argument works?
2. With the assumed lemma holded, is the proof correct? It seems ok to me, though I changed an estimation value.

Thanks!