# How this cellular decomposition of plane region work?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am reading Kodaira's Complex Analysis. In chapter 2 he mentions a theorem about celluar decomposition for plane region (This theorem is used by many calculus book to illustrate Green's theorem too: first prove for region of type I and type II. And then by the decomposition, it holds for any region enclosed by piecewise smooth Jordan curve:)

[image]

Here's the theorem and part of its proof(Sorry I have to quote it as a screenshot. it's too long):

[image]
[image]

I don't understand how the decomposition procedure work, even the author says it's straightforward. How to choose the $\delta$? Is it arbitrary? How does this proof enumerate all the cases? Even for a smooth Jordan curve, it could be quite complicated. For example the following curve(altough it's piecewise smooth) form by $x\sin \frac{1}{x}$ infinitely cross the $x$-axis:

[image]

Edit:

Using the thesis about Green's theorem mentioned in a related question I asked [Cauchy integration theorem for only continuous in the boundary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4449431/cauchy-integration-theorem-for-only-continuous-in-the-boundary) , I got some references.

One is David V.Widder's Advanced Calculus, in the book there is a remark in page193:

[image]

In the remark there is a reference to W. F. Osgood's Lehrbuch der Funktionentheorie. But it's wrote in German.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is the boundary in your example composed of a finite number of Jordan curves? I think not...

Comment: @AakashM It's enclosed by $x \sin \frac{1}{x}$ and $10x(\frac{1}{\pi} - x)$ for $0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{\pi}$. I haven't checked if it's rectifiable. But it should be composed by two smooth Jordan arcs...

Comment: Your curve is not smooth: it's continuous, but not differentiable.

Comment: @aschepler yeah thanks for pointing it out. it's not smooth at point $(0, 0)$ and $(\frac{1}{\pi}, 0)$. So it's only piecewise smooth. Is this right? I try to use it to illustrate that some smooth Jordan curves vibrates infinitely times. I don't know how the proof and the decomposition procedure handle this situation.

Comment: Your boundary is not piecewise smooth, because the sine wave piece (green curve) does not extend to a smooth curve on both endpoints. In other words, the piecewise smooth curves you consider must be smooth embeddings $[a, b] \to \Bbb{R}$ but the green curve is not smooth at the first endpoint. It is .not sufficient to have that point be covered by a different curve (in your case, the black parabola). On the other hand it seems to me that the other book uses the word "regular" to mean a continuously diff.ble curve, which it is, provided that you remove discontinuities at 0.

Comment: Correction, smooth embeddings $[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}^2$

Comment: Yes, what I meant is that the graph of $x \sin \frac{1}{x}$ does not have a derivative at $x=0$ and cannot be extended to a smooth graph. I think the missing detail of the proof is that for a smooth curve, there's some $\delta$ small enough that every square's boundary has at most two intersections with the curve. This seems intuitively true, and I'm thinking proving it might involve knowing that some order of derivative or curvature metric is bounded.

Comment: @NikiDiGiano Ah thanks a lot! I have not noticed that it needs to extend to an open interval including the end points.

Comment: @aschepler I think you are right. I am trying to read Osgood's book using some translation tool. He mentioned out two points: the $\delta$ should be large enough such that there are some squares including their borders being contained inside the interior of $C$;  and other squares intersecting the interior of $C$ are seperated  by $C$ into two region. The second point seems invoking something related to derivative.

Comment: The curve is indeed not rectifiable as the bows of the oscillation give arc lengths $\sim 1/n$ around $x=\frac{2}{(2n+1)\pi}$, the length is asymptotically proportional to a harmonic series.

Comment: It turns out that the screenshots I uploaded is just a sketch of the idea. Kodaira's *Complex Analysis* actually gives a very detailed proof on how the decomposition works (including how to choose the $\delta$ and enumerate all the cases). It's just too long (nearly 20 pages) that at the first glance I didn't realize it's a proof.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks. Nice observation.